# Retrieving Time Zone with Google Geocoder-java

Tags: java, google-geocoder

I am using *Google's Geocoder library*. Specifically `com.google.code.geocoder-java`. I am using the `geocoder-java` version `0.16` from the *Maven* repository. Is there a way to get the time zone using `lat/lng`?

Best Regards,
Steve Mansfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project seems to be deprecated. Try to use the Time Zone API directly:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro

They also have a Java client:

https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/client-library